# Inconsistent wording on empty tag wiki pages.

Tags: bug, status-completed, tagwiki

On empty tag wiki pages, the following text is displayed:

> All registered users may propose new
>   tag wikis. Click **Create Tag Wiki** below
>   to get started.

However, the actual button is “Propose Tag Wiki”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing it to

> Click the button below to get started

since the actual text can vary.